# wp7 xna touch. I want the user to keep tapping, not hold

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, touch

Trying to make an xna game, where the user needs to tap to stop a bar going down. The simulation is like what we see in a WWE PS3/xbox game, the give up bar.

Anyway, the way i have done it, serves the purpose. However, if the user holds the touch, touch values keep incrementing.

What I want is, if the user taps it, only 1 point will be scored. And when he taps again, he will get 1 point more. At the moment what is happening is, if the user holds it, it keeps incrementing, kind of like in a keyboard (if u hold a button, keypresses keeps going on).

```
            foreach (TouchLocation location in TouchPanel.GetState())
            {

                if (location.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)
                {
                    touchPoints++;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from TouchLocationState.Moved to TouchLocationState.Pressed. That should only occur with each new touch.

```
        foreach (TouchLocation location in TouchPanel.GetState())
        {
            TouchLocation prevLocation; 
            bool prevLocationAvailable = location.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLocation);

            if (location.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed && prevLocation.State != TouchLocationState.Pressed)
            {
                touchPoints++;
                break;
            }
        }
```

And for the future, if you're doing Keyboard input and want each press of the keyboard to increment the value but to be ignored if the player is holding down the space, you just have to store the previous state of the keyboard. Then you compare if the current keyboard state the key is being pressed and the previous keyboard state the key wasn't pressed.

(didn't actually code in compiler so there could be some code issues with the below)

```
KeyboardState currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && !previousKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) {
    //Do whatever it is you want to do with the press of the space key
}
previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;
```

Comment: I tried the touchlocation.Pressed(), for some reason, it doesn't register a key press. I had a spritefont used as a debugger. It works with other states, e.g. Released. 

Thanks for the keyboard example, I was using this analogy to explain my problem. Is there anything like previousKeyboardState for touch based thing?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code to include checking the previous state as well. Should be more of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet of my code of how i got each touch to be a individual value.
The system.diagnostics line is the test that will show you in your output box.

```
TouchCollection touch = TouchPanel.GetState();

foreach (TouchLocation touchLocation in touch)
{
    if (touchLocation.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
    {
        base.InputPointX = touchLocation.Position.X;
        base.InputPointY = touchLocation.Position.Y;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X: " + base.InputPointX + \
            ", Y: " + base.InputPointY);
        base.Update();
        return true;
    }
}
```